# Alternate Perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations

Take $H=H^0+H'$

Start with $H^1=H^0+\frac{1}{N}H'$, $N$ is large

Approximating Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions of $H^1$:

$E_n^1=E_n^0+\langle n_0|\frac{1}{N}H'|n_0\rangle$

$|n_1\rangle=|n_0\rangle + \sum _{m} |m_0\rangle \frac{\langle m_0|\frac{1}{N}H'|n_0\rangle}{E_m^0-E_n^0}$

Using these results for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $H^1$, we then solve the Hamiltonian

$H^2=H^1+\frac{1}{N}H'$

to the first order, using the same method:

$E_n^2=E_n^1+\langle n_1 |\frac{1}{N}H'|n_1\rangle$

$|n_2\rangle=|n_1\rangle + \sum _{m} |m_1\rangle \frac{\langle m_1|\frac{1}{N}H'|n_1\rangle}{E_m^1-E_n^1}$

And after iterating $N$ times, we end up solving the original Hamiltonian at the top

Is this method equivalent to the official Perturbation method (the first step is pretty much the same)? If not, why don't we use this method?

The official method is the one with:

$$H|n\rangle=(H_0+H')(|n_0\rangle +|n_1\rangle+...)=(E_n^0+E_n^1+E_n^2+...)|n\rangle$$

Comment: Following your equations, we have $H^2 = H^0 + \frac 2n H'$. Solving this at first order is not the same as solving $H^0 + \frac{1}{n} H'$ at first order.

Comment: @SolubleFish I've edited in that step

Comment: @SolubleFish It's important that we write $H^2$ as $H^1+\frac{1}{N}H'$.  We're solving $H^2$ using the eigenfunctions of $H^1$ found in the previous step.